# can jvm gc size auto increase?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I use java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)
```

I write a simple test:

```
byte[][] bs = new byte[10000][];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
   bs[i] = new byte[1024 * 1024]; // allocate 1M
}
```

get gc detail:

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 32305K->5047K(38400K)] 32305K->26559K(125952K), 0.0182411 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.03, real=0.02 secs] 
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 37429K->4743K(71680K)] 58941K->58007K(159232K), 0.0367694 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.05, real=0.04 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 4743K->0K(71680K)] [ParOldGen: 53264K->57939K(130560K)] 58007K->57939K(202240K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.0320848 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 65784K->4096K(71680K)] 123724K->123476K(202240K), 0.0690420 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.10, real=0.07 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 4096K->0K(71680K)] [ParOldGen: 119380K->123476K(233472K)] 123476K->123476K(305152K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.0111538 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 65789K->4096K(129536K)] 189265K->189013K(363008K), 0.0547978 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.08, real=0.05 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 4096K->0K(129536K)] [ParOldGen: 184917K->189013K(315904K)] 189013K->189013K(445440K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.0166668 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 124258K->4096K(130048K)] 313272K->312919K(445952K), 0.0847352 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.11, real=0.08 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 4096K->0K(130048K)] [ParOldGen: 308823K->312919K(489984K)] 312919K->312919K(620032K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.0097317 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 124268K->5120K(232448K)] 437188K->436825K(722432K), 0.1084567 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.14, real=0.11 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 5120K->0K(232448K)] [ParOldGen: 431705K->436825K(640512K)] 436825K->436825K(872960K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.0105436 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 226600K->5120K(232448K)] 663425K->663133K(891392K), 0.1234434 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.17, real=0.12 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 5120K->5120K(232448K)] [ParOldGen: 658012K->658012K(930816K)] 663133K->663133K(1163264K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.0339242 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.04 secs] 
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 231734K->5120K(427008K)] 889747K->889440K(1357824K), 0.2574536 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.20, real=0.26 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 5120K->0K(427008K)] [ParOldGen: 884320K->889440K(1209856K)] 889440K->889440K(1636864K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.0407911 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.02, real=0.04 secs] 
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 421376K->5120K(428032K)] 1310816K->1310310K(1734656K), 0.3690828 secs] [Times: user=0.24 sys=0.44, real=0.37 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 5120K->4096K(428032K)] [ParOldGen: 1305190K->1306214K(1398272K)] 1310310K->1310310K(1826304K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.0325402 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 425984K->331781K(428032K)] [ParOldGen: 1306214K->1397352K(1398272K)] 1732198K->1729133K(1826304K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.1704718 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.14, real=0.17 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 421888K->420870K(428032K)] [ParOldGen: 1397352K->1397352K(1398272K)] 1819240K->1818222K(1826304K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 0.0321183 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
[Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 420870K->420870K(428032K)] [ParOldGen: 1397352K->1397315K(1398272K)] 1818222K->1818185K(1826304K), [Metaspace: 4229K->4229K(1056768K)], 2.7526882 secs] [Times: user=3.41 sys=1.22, real=2.76 secs]
```

Before young gc space size is 38400K and old gen size is 130560K, but finally the young gc space size is 428032K and old gen size is 1826304K.

Can jvm gc size auto increase? So should I config the gc size ?

Comment: why don't you just set an Xmx if you need more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can jvm gc size auto increase?

It does increase automatically, that why you have an initial size `-ms` or `-Xms` and a maximum size `-mx` or `-Xmx`.

You should set the `-mx` to be the size you would rather than program die rather than use more heap.

> So should I config the gc size ?

If you want to use 10GB of heap I suggest making your maximum heap at least 11 GB e.g. `-Xmx11g` but only after checking your machine has say 12 GB of free main memory.